# How to check if custom field exist even if meta value is empty in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have a pretty working condition to check if custom field exist, this is the line:

```
if (((get_post_meta($post->ID, $my_metakey, TRUE))=='')
```

However as you have noticed, it will only be effective to check for meta key if its value is set to empty.

I would like to know how to check if the custom field name/meta key already exist in the database even if I set the meta value to empty or blank at defaults.

Is there an efficient approach of doing this with WordPress?
Thanks for any tip.

Update: Also this one won't work:

```
<?php if (strlen(get_post_meta($post->ID, $metakey, true)) > 0) : ?>
```

As it is similar to checking if the custom field is empty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With WP 3.3.0 there is a better way: use cache and apply filters

```
 metadata_exists( 'post', $post->ID, $my_metakey )
```

Answer (score 4):

The custom fields values are stored in `wp_postmeta` WordPress database table. So just use this :

```
$test = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_key FROM wp_postmeta where meta_key='name_of_custom_field'" );
if (($wpdb->num_rows)>0) {
    // custom field exists
}
else {
    // field does not exist 
}
```

Comment: I get your point, that seems to be a feasible solution but how to alter it if you are checking if the meta key already exist for a specific post_id?

Comment: I personnaly think your code was fine for that! (empty field=no field). The way you asked was: does it exist anywhere (for any post) in the database?  Otherwise, instead of checking equality with empty string (`==''`), just use PHP's `isset()`.